# Missing an excellent answer about JavaScript frameworks

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, historical-lock

There used to be an excellent question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs). The answers were so excellent that the question was linked to from [Mozilla's learning page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript). I very much hope that this question can be restored.

Comment: I can't see the post (need 10k reputation to see deleted content), but based on the title, it sounds like it was deleted because it was not a good fit (it (again, based only on the title in the link) was a [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) post). As such, it is unlikely that it will come back.

Comment: @Jim: Closed as Not Constructive (it was a shopping question).

Comment: Theoretically, the question could be undeleted and protected as historical. But that's up to the mods.

Comment: Which answer did you consider "excellent"?

Comment: It has been restored!

Answer (score 17):

With over 200,000 views and dozens of inbound links to that page, I think it qualifies for a historical lock.

Comment: I think the popularity requirement that grew according to the number of votes on the question and its answers worked fine before they tweaked it. It would've taken hundreds of votes to delete this one and we wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: The problem with this question is that it has a lot of bad answer (1st and 3rd answer are good example) which are partly outdated, make claim that aren't back with anything, just tell the name of a library, etc. Since it now has a historical lock, bad answer are just going to stay on top and nobody can fix outdated statement. I'm not that sure it's a good idea to keep that question open with a historical lock.

Comment: @HoLyVieR You make a valid point.  Normally, by the time a post gets a historical lock it's already been cleaned up.  I just went through and deleted some of the one-liner, link-only, and duplicate answers.